# How to correctly have a smooth preloader fade out

Tags: jquery

I am using this script I found on the internet, but the fadeout is not working. I want a smooth fadeout.

```js
var loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //Hide the spinner after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    loader.style.display = 'none';
  }, 2000);
});

$("#spinner").fadeOut();
```

```html
<section id="spinner">
  <div id="preloader">Loading...</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code relies on jQuery.js - have you added that to the page? Also, the last line need to replace `loader.style.display = ...`

Comment: Glad it helped - I added it as an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you need to include a reference to the jQuery.js script in the page, and you also need to call the `fadeOut()` line in the handler for the `setTimeout()`, so that it runs when the 2 seconds have elapsed. Try this:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#spinner").fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="spinner">
  <div id="preloader">Loading...</div>
</section>
```